# QuickBlox getUsersByFilter()

Tags: android, sorting, filter, quickblox

I am in a situation where i need to get the users from quickblox sorted by last_request_at in descending order.

On my reasearch I have come upon this method.

```
public static QBRequestCanceler getUsersByFilter(Collection<?> filterValue, String filter, QBPagedRequestBuilder requestBuilder, QBEntityCallback<ArrayList<QBUser>> callback)
```

I can use it to filter users by id.
The documentation also points out that it can be used for sorting :
http://quickblox.com/developers/Users#Filters

If it works the way I need it to , can someone share an example with the params they used to achieve the desired result ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add the following parameter to the request:

```
QBPagedRequestBuilder requestBuilder = new QBPagedRequestBuilder();
        ArrayList<GenericQueryRule> rules = new ArrayList<>();
        rules.add(new GenericQueryRule("order", "desc date last_request_at"));

        requestBuilder.setRules(rules);
```